# Modifying bluetoothctl automation script - How to remove output from expect & spawn?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bluetooth, expect

I'm trying to automate the pairing of my headset to my ubuntu16 machine.

I took [this nice script](https://gist.github.com/RamonGilabert/046727b302b4d9fb0055) and tried it, but it didn't work. I played around a bit, and found out that I can just work with this minimal script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set prompt '#'
set address [lindex $argv 0]

spawn bluetoothctl &> /dev/null
expect -re $prompt
send "\nconnect <my_mac_addr>\r"
sleep 10
```

I save this as a ./bluetooth.sh and run it with ./bluetooth.sh & and it works like a charm. However, I get this annoying `bluetoothctl` output:

```
[NEW] Controller *** ### [default]
[NEW] Device *** A
[NEW] Device *** B
[NEW] Device *** C
[bluetooth]#
```

I tried removing it with the redirection I added to the spawn command, but it didn't help as you can see...

*Removing the `expect` would work, but I'm not sure this is the way to go...*

Comment: Does this help? [Hide output from expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654683/4440445)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to use `expect` and can give commands to `bluetoothctl` directly as arguments.

```bsh
# ...
bluetoothctl -- power on
bluetoothctl -- connect $mac
# ...
```

For a more complete example, here is the full Bash script that I use in Ubuntu 20.04 for my BT radio :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mac="90:03:B7:17:00:08" # DEH-4400BT

if [ "$1" = "off" ]; then
    bluetoothctl -- disconnect
    exit $?
fi

# turn on bluetooth in case it's off
rfkill unblock bluetooth

bluetoothctl -- power on
bluetoothctl -- connect $mac

# Use it as default output for PulseAudio

sink=$(pactl list short sinks | grep bluez | awk '{print $2}')

if [ -n "$sink" ]; then
    pacmd set-default-sink "$sink" && echo "OK default sink : $sink"
else
    echo could not find bluetooth sink
    exit 1
fi
```

This assumes the destination `$mac` is already paired of course.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the output and strip the prompts...

```
typeset -a OUTPUT

clean_line () {
   local LINE

   while read LINE;do
      echo ${LINE} | perl -pe 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mG]//g; s/\[.*\]#?//g; s/\x0d\x1b\x20\x0d\x1b\x5b\x4b//g; s/^ //g'
   done
}

coproc bluetoothctl
echo -e 'agent on\nconnect 00:0C:8A:FE:ED:18\nexit' >&p 
OUTPUT=("${(f)$(cat <&p | clean_line)}")

NDX=0
for L in ${OUTPUT};do
   ((NDX++))
   printf "%d) %s\n" ${NDX} ${L}
done
```